# Google Sign in not working after migrating to AndroidX

Tags: android, google-signin, androidx

I have integrated Google Sign in my android app. It was working perfectly when I used spp compact v28 libraries but it is failing after mygrating my app to androidx with the below exception.

```
java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Class 'com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.internal.SignInHubActivity' does not implement interface 'androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleOwner' in call to 'androidx.lifecycle.Lifecycle androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleOwner.getLifecycle()' (declaration of 'androidx.lifecycle.LiveData' appears in /data/app/com.grecloud-2/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk:classes89.dex)
        at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.observe(LiveData.java:172)
        at androidx.loader.app.LoaderManagerImpl$LoaderInfo.setCallback(LoaderManagerImpl.java:100)
        at androidx.loader.app.LoaderManagerImpl.createAndInstallLoader(LoaderManagerImpl.java:400)
        at androidx.loader.app.LoaderManagerImpl.initLoader(LoaderManagerImpl.java:421)
        at com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.internal.SignInHubActivity.zzn(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.internal.SignInHubActivity.onActivityResult(Unknown Source)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6500)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3936)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3983)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap16(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1548)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5765)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679)
```

The activity that has code for Google Sign In extends `AppCompatActivity` and implements `GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, View.OnClickListener`

Comment: Please add your activity code as well with the imports you are using.

Comment: I'am having the same issue, following for this

Comment: Same issue. Any solution?

Comment: [Link](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/119886472) to the Android bug that appears to be filed by the author. Note that there is a workaround in [comment #7](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/119886472#comment7) that apparently works for some people (but not me). Also note that the issue is marked as blocked by another non-public issue so hopefully that means it is being addressed behind the scenes despite the lack of official response in the public bug. I recommend starring the Android bug to indicate interest in having it fixed (instead of adding a me too comment).

Answer (score 1):

After **removing** the following 2 lines in build.gradle it is working for me:

```
implementation "androidx.media:media:1.1.0-alpha01"
implementation "androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0"
```

Comment: I noticed that when you use Android Studio’s Migrate option for AndroidX, strangely it updates the project but with alpha version of the libraries instead of using the production version. Changing the alpha libs to proper version as mentioned in the above comment worked for me.