# Has anyone got this google signin error after migrating to androidx

Tags: android, google-signin, androidx

```
 java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Class 'com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.internal.SignInHubActivity' does not implement interface 'androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleOwner' in call to 'androidx.lifecycle.Lifecycle androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleOwner.getLifecycle()' (declaration of 'androidx.lifecycle.LiveData' appears in /data/app/in.jokebox-R9DyXTIhmjKoz2FZcm96Ng==/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk)
        at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.observe(LiveData.java:172)
        at androidx.loader.app.LoaderManagerImpl$LoaderInfo.setCallback(LoaderManagerImpl.java:100)
        at androidx.loader.app.LoaderManagerImpl.createAndInstallLoader(LoaderManagerImpl.java:400)
        at androidx.loader.app.LoaderManagerImpl.initLoader(LoaderManagerImpl.java:421)
        at com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.internal.SignInHubActivity.zzn(Unknown Source:80)
        at com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.internal.SignInHubActivity.onActivityResult(Unknown Source:68)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:7454)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4378)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4427)
        at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityResultItem.execute(ActivityResultItem.java:49)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1821)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:114)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:198)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6716)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Dependency for google signin:

implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1'

Comment: Likely a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53416807/google-sign-in-not-working-after-migrating-to-androidx

Comment: Yeah, but there is no solution offered there also and i am not even using androidx media or legacy dependencies.